# Switching from svn to git: Can searching logs for svn commit and showing commit in git be done in a one-liner?

Tags: git, git-svn, git-log, git-show

I know that you can search for an `svn commit` after running `git svn` using the `git log` command.

Example searching for svn commit r88843:

```
git log --grep=git-svn-id:.*@88843
```

Then you can use the git commit hash  to pass into `git show`

Can this be done in a one-liner?

Similar to (in Linux):

```
git show < git log --grep=git-svn-id:.*@88843 --pretty=format:%H
```

Comment: And what OS you are working on?

Comment: Linux / FreeBSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to view patch output, you can just use the `-p` option to `git log`, and it will show the patch output as well as the log information.  That's nearly equivalent to `git show` and is likely the easiest way to get what you want.

However, if you really want to use `git show`, you can use either one of the following:

```
$ git show $(git log --grep=git-svn-id:.*@88843 --pretty=format:%H)
```

or, if you expect to have many arguments, you can use:

```
$ git log --grep=git-svn-id:.*@88843 --pretty=format:%H | xargs git show
```